# ggplot2 stat_function - can we use the generated y values on other layers

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question arose when I was trying to draw a standard normal distribution with ggplot (easy to do with stat_function) and also color the area under the curve for different quintiles -

[image]

I was able to do this with geom_line and geom_ribbon after I created a data frame with a range of values for x and the corresponding dnorm values for each x as y

```
    data = data.frame(x=seq(-3,3,length.out=1000))
data$y=dnorm(data$x)
data$Quintile <- with(data,ifelse(x<qnorm(0.2),"Bottom",
                               ifelse(x<qnorm(0.4),"Second",
                                      ifelse(x<qnorm(0.6),"Middle",
                                             ifelse(x<qnorm(0.8),"Fourth","Top")))))
data$Quintile <- factor(data$Quintile, levels=c("Bottom","Second","Middle","Fourth","Top"))

ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=Quintile))+geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=y),ymin=0,alpha=0.5)+
  geom_line(color="black")+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkgreen","red","purple","blue","gray"))+
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(qnorm(c(0.2,0.4,0.6,.8))),color=c("darkgreen","red","purple","blue"),size=1)+
  scale_y_continuous("",breaks=NULL)+scale_x_continuous("",breaks=NULL)
```

I find it more appealing to use stat_function and I guess it must be creating its set of y values to plot the line - I tried to access those on other layers to add the colored bands but was unable to do it - I want to see if someone can explain how that can be done or why we can't

In other words instead of generating data myself, and use geom_line to draw the curve, I want to do something like

```
ggplot(NULL,aes(x=c(-3,3))) + stat_function(fun=dnorm)
```

and the use the data that stat_function generated to do the coloring - I was not able to get access the generated y values (i tried using ..y.. for example)

Is there a way to use those values? if so how?

Comment: You'll make it easier to help you if you provide the code you used to create your data frame and draw your plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ggplot(NULL,aes(x=c(-3,3))) + 
  stat_function(fun=dnorm, geom="ribbon",
                mapping = aes(ymin=0,ymax=..y..))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this works up to a level - you can color the entire curve that way - but the idea is to color quartiles or quintiles in different colors - how would one color say the area from -3 to 0 one color and the area from zero with another with the appraoch

Comment: i doubt it's possible, stat_function doesn't seem to play well with the idea of aesthetic mappings. You'll probably have to create the data outside ggplot.

Comment: Baptiste, thanks for the answer. I really was just asking to see if it was an 'elegant' solution without creating the data - always looking to write less code whenever possible

Comment: your expectation is reasonable, but I fear stat_function is rather a recent addition, and maybe not quite as polished as other parts of the package because it was written only for user convenience, not as an integral component.

Answer (score 3):

You can use stat_function. See link below for an example.

http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/58753_13e35d9c089d4f55b176057235778679.html

Example plot:

[image]

Comment: What when you want to use a function such as `dweibull`? Then you get an `argument ... missing` and ` args=list(..)` does not help.

Comment: @fitzy_blarb I'd recommend posting this as a question on SO with a reproducible example and with more information about what exactly your already tried